# Sails js Undeclared Variable: NaN when modelling associations

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have two Models in Sails - Users and Absences. A User has many records of Absences so i'm trying to do a One to Many association. They look like this:

User.js
in attributes:

```
id: {
    type: 'integer',
    unique: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    columnName: 'idx'
},
absences: {
    collection: 'absence',
    via: 'idxuser'
}
```

Absence.js
in attributes:

```
id: {
    type: 'integer',
    unique: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    columnName: 'idx'
},
idxuser: {
    model: 'user'
}
```

But when I call a user record I get this error:

```
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
ER_SP_UNDECLARED_VAR: Undeclared variable: NaN
```

and the stack trace references the sails-mysql module.

I'm using:
sails 0.10.5
sails-mysql 0.10.6
node 0.10.25

Comment: This works perfectly me for me with a new database and the exact code you posted.  Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I meet this exception too. But, DB has null value in column. that type of attribute is 'integer'. 
First check your values in DB.